# how to store table of data in sqlite?

Tags: android

I am new to android.

I am been working with `sqlite.`

Through sqlite i am creating two tables like `table1,table2`

table1 is looking like this

```
key_id    Names   places
 1         pal      us
 2         jan      uk
```

table 2 is looking like this

```
key_id      designation    salary
 1           employee       100$
 2           employee        200$
```

i want to store this two tables and send through a mail.

If any one has the solution please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are new to android you should work on this tutorial http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html
to learn how to use SQLite in android and read Dev Guide. Good luck.